# Httpd with api gateway [AWS] : Error reading from remote server

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

In my use case i have to make an api gateway accessible by a reverse proxy.
something like this :
(users -> Httpd(EC2) -> api gateway -> lambda)

I was able to create a vpc-link between my api gateway and my virtual machine EC2( it's working perfectly).

but the second part is to create a server httpd which will redirecte the requests from other networks to my api gateway.

but my httpd server seems not working
here the error

```
Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /myapi/.

Reason: Error reading from remote server
```

here my httpd configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    # Use HTTP Strict Transport Security to force client to use secure connections only 
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=300; includeSubDomains; preload"


    ServerAdmin administrator@test.net
    ServerName  www.test.net
    ServerAlias test.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test.net/public_html/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/selfsigned/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/selfsigned/server.key

    SSLProxyEngine On


    ProxyPass /myapi/   https://apigateway.amazonaws.com/ retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=24000 Keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse /myapi/    https://apigateway.amazonaws.com/


    ProxyPreserveHost On





</VirtualHost>
```

NB: the lambda function return a simple response.

do you have an idea ?

thank you in advance

Comment: Do you really have `https://apigateway.amazonaws.com` in your web server configuration?

Comment: Your api url looks like https://<api-id>.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/test not  https://apigateway.amazonaws.com/ which is used for management of apis in api gateway.

Comment: I have api-id..., i just renamed the url, because i don't want to share my real api gateway url in the internet. that is not a problem, because i can perfectely run curl apigateway_amazon_url